# Extending existing classes by adding instance variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

in Objective-C if I need to add additional method to UIButton I can use *Categories* for that. Is there any easy way (except subclassing) to add additional instance variable or property (instance variable + getter/setter).
Let's say I want to store UIColor reference in UIButton.

PS: It is mor theory question. I already implemented that using subclassing but looking for "nicer" way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution is to use associative references; not as fast as ivars, but quite useful.

I.e. given:

```
@interface UIButton (color)
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *myPrefixColor;
@end
```

You could implement this as:

```
@implementation UIButton (color) 
static const char *assocKey = "myPrefixColor associated object key";
- (void) setMyPrefixColor: (UIColor*) aColor
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &assocKey, aColor, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
- (UIColor*)myPrefixColor;
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &assocKey);
}
@end
```

The `myPrefix` stuff is because you should **never** add methods to existing classes without prefixing 'em with something such that the chance of a collision with an existing method (that you aren't aware of) are minimized.

Comment: I believe in implementation part should be `UIColor` instead of `NSString`, right?

Comment: I think for my case it will be better to use sub-classing as I don't need that functionality from 100% of UIButton instances. Anyway was good to know.

Comment: Yup;  muscle memory belies the # of years I've been doing this. Thanks. :)  And, yes, subclassing is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add ivars using categories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to add ivars to classes to which you don't have the source. Two technologies come close: Categories let you add instance methods, but not instance variables, and class extensions let you add instance variables by declaring properties, but the compiler enforces the implementation of those properties' methods from within the implementation block of the class, which you don't have access to. They're designed to aid the implementation of private interfaces, not really extend classes that already exist.

Comment: You are probably right - it's not designed to add i-vars. But anyways - it IS possible!